# PHP - Putting a date into a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have what is most likely a very simple question.. I am designing a simple blogging system and I am trying to put the current date into the table where the blog post is stored whilst waiting for administrator approval. but the method I have used puts 0000-00-00 into the date column! What I am using is as follows:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO blogentry VALUES ('".$mnam."','".date('d-m-Y h:m:s') ."\n"."','".$mcom."','".$approve."')";
```

I am relatively new to php so stumble accross errors like this all the time... but I cant seem to google this one!

Thanks guys!

Comment: i would make a suggsetion, use now() and record the epoch timestamp instead. Then, just use date() to convert it back to human readable.

Comment: While you're learning php, please do yourself a favour and look into PDO, it is the correct way to interface with any database in php...do not use mysql_query() directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the easiest way to do this is just let MySQL handle it with the `NOW()` function:

```
INSERT INTO blogentry VALUES( ..., NOW(), ... )
```

Another option is to use `TIMESTAMP`s by changing your table - set the column to type `TIMESTAMP` with `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and you can just ignore that column when inserting - it will automatically be filled with the current time. You will need to specify the columns you're inserting to in order to skip a column:

```
INSERT INTO blogentry( column1, column2 ) VALUES( column1value, column2value )
```

Finally, you **NEED** to sanitize your inputs. Preferably using prepared statements and PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), or at least using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL manual on [DATE, DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

> The **DATE** type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays **DATE** values in **'YYYY-MM-DD'** format. The
>   supported range is **'1000-01-01'** to **'9999-12-31'**.

This means you have to insert the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  You are using `date('d-m-Y h:m:s')` format.  Change that to `date('Y-m-d')` and it should insert correctly.

If you want the time as well, then you need to change the column datatype to `DATETIME` and then insert using the format `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.

As other mention, you can use an `INT` column type instead and store a Unix timestamp which is stored in UTC so it is more portable.  You can then easily manipulate the timestamp to output the date any way you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Try just storing a [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) result.  It creates a unique timestamp, which can then be parsed however you need it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to give the timestamp to the date function:

```
date('d-m-Y h:m:s', strtotime('now'))
```

Also, to do a standard datetime format:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'))
```